# Como puedo anadir un scroll bar en mi lista? hecha con table?

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo un tabla que muestra los resultados y como traigo todo eso de la base de datos, si fuera demasiados quiero evitarme que el div se alargue, por lo que se me ocurrio meter la parte en donde se imprimen los resultados dentro de un div y poner bajar mediante scrollbar, pero no se en donde meterlo y aplicarlo, aqui les dejo el codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el scroll comenzaria en todo el cuadro rojo, aqui el codigo:

```
<table id="prueba">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">
                        <input v-model="product" @input="findproduct" placeholder="Search by name"></input>
                        <a href="index.php"><button>Back</button></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name:</th>
                    <th>Lot:</th> 
                    <th>Quantity packed</th>
                    <th>Quantity of pallets</th>
                </tr>
                <tr v-for="i in listFinishedproducts">
                    <td>{{i.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.lot}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.quantity_packed}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.pallet}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes implementar la siguiente solución. En este caso debes insertar un div con un height determinado, un overflow auto y a continuación una segunda tabla en la que mostrar los resultados. De este modo la tabla quedará contenida en ese div:

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="325">
  <tr>
    <td>
       <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="300" >
         <tr style="color:white;background-color:grey">
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
         </tr>
       </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <div style="width:320px; height:150px; overflow:auto;">
         <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="300" >
           <tr>
             <td>new item</td>
             <td>new item</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>new item</td>
             <td>new item</td>
           </tr>
              <tr>
             <td>new item</td>
             <td>new item</td>
           </tr>
              <tr>
             <td>new item</td>
             <td>new item</td>
           </tr>
              <tr>
             <td>new item</td>
             <td>new item</td>
           </tr>
              <tr>
             <td>new item</td>
             <td>new item</td>
           </tr>
              <tr>
             <td>new item</td>
             <td>new item</td>
           </tr>
              <tr>
             <td>new item</td>
             <td>new item</td>
           </tr>
              <tr>
             <td>new item</td>
             <td>new item</td>
           </tr>
              <tr>
             <td>new item</td>
             <td>new item</td>
           </tr>
         </table>  
       </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda.

Comment: Detalles de la respuesta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834198/table-scroll-with-html-and-css)

Answer (score 0):

en el css de table

```
#prueba{
display: block;
overflow:auto;
}
```

display: block; para generar un bloque (de este podes prescindir) y overflow:auto; para que en caso de desbordamiento tu navegador añada un scroll.